# Can I add custom fields to a single page?

Tags: entities

Sorry for another "In Wordpress..." question but here we go...

In Wordpress, I can use ACF to add custom fields to a single page. This is done either in code or in the GUI by basically doing something like (pseudocode),

```
if id = 123
  add_field "Phone Number"
end
```

This is especially useful on homepages or landing pages where the layout is unique and I want to provide structured data entry without needing to create a custom type that is only used once. In Drupal, I dont see a way to dynamically add fields to an arbitrary piece of content. Is this possible? How?

---

*Wordpress custom fields:*
[image]

Comment: I would actually add a new content type just for this case ... or perhaps you can play around with paragraphs they might fit you are trying to accomplish

Comment: As I was writing the question, I was thinking that I may just have to resort to single-use content types. It feels a little overkill, if I can get past that, then it seems to hit on all the other requirements I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Drupal 8, you can create a block type and add fields to it. Then create a block of your block type and on visibility rules you can assign it to a specific page.

- [Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J20r-arq6Kg).

If you're using Drupal 7, you can do the same, but you'll need the [Bean](https://www.drupal.org/project/bean) module